# kivy executes "on_release"-command multiple times

Tags: python, ubuntu, kivy

To trigger the acquisition of an image, I use the `on_release`-function of a [kivy-button](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.button.html).

So, whenever this button is clicked (or *pressed* -- since using a touchscreen) a camera is triggered using [gphoto2](http://gphoto.org/).

**The issue:**
From time to time, the function is executed multiple times (taking multiple images), while it was clearly pressed only a single time.

According to the logs, I'm confident, that it's a kivy-related issue (not related to the camera, etc.): Logging entries within the `on_release`-function appear multiple times within the logs.

I'm running an app with kivy (version 1.9.0) and python (version 2.7.6) under Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (64bit) using a touchscreen.

Any hint on how to debug or fix the issue is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck at the same problem for days!

Do you have this line in your code?

```py
Config.set('input', 'mouse', 'mouse, multitouch_on_demand')
```

If yes, then remove it.

On touch devices, touch gets triggered multiple times.

Hope it helps someone with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could disable the button when the first release event starts, and in the end of the thread where the picture is taken, enable the button again. Then you will not have multiple events from that button executing, but still the main app thread is allowed to continue.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
import time
import threading

Builder.load_string('''

<MyLayout>:
    Button:
        text: 'Print to terminal'
        on_release: 
            root.button_released(self)
''')


class MyLayout(BoxLayout):

    def button_released(self,button):
        button.disabled = True
        print("{} pressed!".format(button))
        threading.Thread(target=self.take_picture, args=(button,)).start()

    def take_picture(self,button):
        time.sleep(1)  # taking picture or whatever
        button.disabled = False

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return MyLayout()


MyApp().run()
```